# Does $f_t=\frac{z}{t}$ converges to $f(z)=z$ uniformly on $\mathbb{\hat C}$ as $t\nearrow 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does $f_t=\frac{z}{t}$ converges to $f(z)=z$ uniformly on $\mathbb{\hat C}$ as $t\nearrow 1$? I know it doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$. But I am always confused about $\mathbb{\hat C}$. Any suggests?

Comment: Id $\hat{\mathbb C}$ the Riemann sphere?

Comment: Yes. $\mathbb{\hat C}$ is the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Is the Riemann sphere compact? What is the codomain?

Comment: Riemann sphere is compact. And $f_t(z)=\frac{z}{t}:\mathbb{\hat C}\to\mathbb{\hat C}$.

Comment: It converges uniformly If $t\in [a,b]$ and $0$ does not belong to $[a,b]$,

Comment: What metric are you using on the Riemann sphere?